# Let $f$: $X \to Y$ be a function. Show that if $f$ is injective then $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ for sets $A \subseteq X$ and $B \subseteq X$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let : $X \to  Y$ be a function. Show that if $f$ is injective then $f(A \cap  B) = f(A) \cap  f(B)$ for
sets $A \subseteq  X$ and $B \subseteq  X$.

My answer :

Suppose $f$ is injective and $f(x) \in   f(A \cap  B) \Leftrightarrow  x \in  A \cap  B  \Leftrightarrow  x \in  A$ and $x \in  B \Leftrightarrow $ $  f(x) \in  f(A)$ and $f(x) \in  f(B) \Leftrightarrow  f(x) \in  f(A) \cap  f(B)$. Therefore as each step is an equivalence it can be read backwards so $f(A \cap  B) \subseteq  f(A) \cap  f(B)$ and $f(A) \cap  f(B)$ $ \subseteq  f(A \cap  B)$ meaning $f(A \cap  B) = f(A) \cap  f(B)$.

What I don't understand is where this proof breaks down if $f$ is not injective ?

Comment: Some counterexamples can be found, for example, here: [Do we have always $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170725).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It breaks reading backwards here:

> $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ $\Leftrightarrow f(x) \in f(A)$ and $f(x)\in f(B)$

You can't guarantee that it is the same $x$ that gives the value $f(x)$. To be more exact, you should have taken $y \in f(A)\cap f(B)$. Then $y \in f(A)$ and $y \in f(B)$. So exists $x_1\in A$ and $x_2 \in B$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2) = y$. Injectivity assures that $x_1=x_2$, and then your argument follows.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is not injective, there might be some $y\notin A\cap B$ such that $f(y)=f(x)$.

For example if you take $A=B=\{x\}$ you have that $\{y,x\}\subseteq\{w\mid f(w)=f(x)\}$. But of course $y\notin A\cap B=\{x\}$.

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you.